# OAuth call for a request token yields a 400 error

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-j

I want to obtain an Access Token is for my application using the Authorization Code it just acquired. I am using this code

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https")
        .setHost("www.linkedin.com")
        .setPath("/uas/oauth2/accessToken")
        .setParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code")
        .setParameter("code", code)
        .setParameter("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:9090/ConnectSocialMedia/callBack.jsp")
        .setParameter("client_id", CONSUMER_KEY_OPTION)
        .setParameter("client_secret", CONSUMER_SECRET_OPTION)
        .build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("Final Response------------>"+response2);
```

But I am getting **HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the parameters to the token endpoint as query parameters in the URL but they should be passed in the POST parameters. You should use something like:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("https")
    .setHost("www.linkedin.com")
    .setPath("/uas/oauth2/accessToken")
    .build();

List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:9090/ConnectSocialMedia/callBack.jsp"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", CONSUMER_KEY_OPTION));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", CONSUMER_SECRET_OPTION));

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(post);
System.out.println("Final Response------------>"+response2);
```